# How can I filter the related list using the ApexPages.StandardController's getRecord() method?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a VF Page which should not include any **Cancelled** OpportunityLineItems.

In the apex controller,

```
public myClass(ApexPages.StandardController stdController){
        id = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        opportunity = (Opportunity)stdController.getRecord();
```

How should I filter the OLIs from the above Opportunity record?

I've tried using the below:

```
        List<String> oppFields = new List<String>(Schema.Opportunity.SObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().keySet());
        String soqlDynamicQuery = ' SELECT ' + String.join(oppFields, ',')
            +', (SELECT Id, ServiceDate, Quantity, TotalPrice FROM OpportunityLineItems WHERE Cancelled__c = false) '
            + ' FROM Opportunity WHERE Id=:id';
        
        opportunity = (Opportunity)Database.query(soqlDynamicQuery);
```

This will not work because I have a bunch of related fields like Account.Name, Account.BillingCity, foo__r.Name etc., which will throw an error: *SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Opportunity.Account*

The only workaround that I found was to include ALL the fields that am using in the VF page in the SOQL.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be the correct and easiest way to include the specific field in apex that you are using in the VF. That's not a workaround. You can also go ahead and use querybuilder libraries like Query.apex which handles dynamic query creation

Comment: This method is not ideal because the SOQL keeps increasing whenever we add fields to the Visualforce page. I already tried the dynamic query which doesn't help.